# Changing Margins Depending on Browser Width Javascript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make an "Additional Comments" box on my website, which floats to the right of the page, while there's 4 inputs on the right.

For some reason, the comments box, on browser resizing, sits behind the inputs.

I want to make it so that when the browser is less than, say for example, 400px, it applies a margin to the comments box. I tried the below, but that didn't seem to work.

```
var browserSize = window.innerWidth();
    var additional = document.getElementById("additional");

    if(browserSize < 400px) {
        additional.style.marginTop = "200px";
    }
```

Could someone guide me as to where to go?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is CSS media queries option for you? Or you have to use JS for this?

Comment: Yes, they worked, as suggested by Ralph David Abernathy. Just to lack of experience, I thought JS would be the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use CSS media queries? You can do something like this in a stylesheet:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #additional {
        margin-top: 200px;
    }
}
```

However, you should try to avoid using IDs as CSS selectors as much as possible.

Comment: Ahh, that should work! Thanks very much. I'm familiar with CSS, but I haven't looked into the media side of it. Appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem, you should look into SCSS. It makes writing media-queries much easier! Check out http://thesassway.com/intermediate/responsive-web-design-in-sass-using-media-queries-in-sass-32

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener for browser resize and a function for your work inside it:

```
function processResize()
{
var browserSize = window.innerWidth();
    var additional = document.getElementById("additional");

    if(browserSize < 400px) {
        additional.style.marginTop = "200px";
    }
}
window.addEventListener("resize", processResize);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm sorted with using media queries, but thanks for answering with JS! I'm sure this'll come in handy in the future. Many thanks!